# Unable to ssh from windows to Linux machine getting error ssh: connect to host "Ip Address" port 22: Bad file number

Tags: linux, ssh

I trying to SSH to Linux machine and getting this error **Bad file number**
I hit this command on GitBash

```
$ ssh host_name@IP address
```

> ssh: connect to IP address port 22: Bad file number

Please help me.
Previously I am able ssh to Linux machine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just should do :

```
ssh -T user@ip
```

If you have a passphrase, you have to write it after when it will be asked. Then you'll get a success message.

That has worked for me.